# Dynamically assign name to object array

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript issue. 
If I have an object array objAr, the object consists of id,name.

If I was to access `objAr[0].id` it returns the id value of the first object. What would happen if the object is dynamic and therefore I do not know what it consists of, is there a way to dynamically call the Object attribute?

Currently I am creating another array

```
var theArr = new Array("id", "name");
```

and call:

```
objAr[0].theArr[0] instead of objAr[0].id.
```

Is there a way to do this better using Javascript?

Comment: You want to iterate over the properties ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/loop-through-javascript-object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Javascript you can call all of the attributes in an object without knowing the keys.

See below:

```
for(key in objAr[0]) {
   console.log(objAr[0][key]);
}
```

If you just wanted the first attribute you could run:

```
for(key in objAr[0]) {
   var attFirst = objAr[0][key];
   break;
}
```

Additionally for the JS array you could have used square brackets.

```
var theArr = ["id", "name"];
```

hope that helps

Comment: Remember the `if (objAr[0].hasOwnProperty(key))` check to avoid iterating over the...'inherited'/'native' properties of the object (unless you really want to).

Comment: The _"first attribute"_  sample can do without the `for` loop, I'd suggest using a `if`, instead.

Comment: this worked, useful to know additional stuff thanks

Answer (score 0):

In javascript you can always use the "array notation" in place of the "dot notation"

So these 2 lines are the same

```
objAr[0].id
objAr[0]["id"]
```